# SwiftData - 'self' used in property access 'persistentBackingData' before 'super.init' call

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, init, swift-data

I was trying to set a class to be a persistent data source using `@Model` annotation, and somehow this happened:

[image]

The code above is generated by the compiler and the error is located in it.

Here is my code:

```swift
import SwiftData

class Animal {
}

@Model
class Dog: Animal {
    let breed: String
    init(breed: String) {
        self.breed = breed
    }
}
```

However, when I declare the Dog class with no super class, it work as expected.

Any idea?

Comment: Don't use inheritance together with SwiftData, that's my recommendation. Maybe it will work later but right now the Model macro doesn't support it.

Comment: I was trying to use SwiftData in my project, and the same error occurred when I tried to apply the `@Model` annotation to a class that inherits from `NSObject`. Turns out the issue is related to a model with inheritance.

Comment: 1) it's a shame .. if You use class you must allow it, otherwise us struct 2) worse is that you cannot use a class marked with @model in other target where you don't have swiftData available, for example inside an XCTest